# Get values followed by duplicates values in sql

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a value in a column in sql

```
1
2
3
1
4
5
```

My expected output is

```
123
145
```

I need a sql statement to achieve the above result

I didn't get the proper result by using rank and row number function
What needs to be done to get the expected output. What function must be used

Comment: Hy, Welcome to stack overflow, can you please post an example of your table using the editor's formatting options and add your SQL request.

Comment: Your question _cannot_ be answered sans one or more other columns which provides the ordering in your source table which you seem to think exists.

Comment: what is the logic behind this and also add the code you already have. Are the numbers always combine in three

Comment: It need not to be 3. Whenever the there is 1 it should start pulling the value 1 and its following values unit it find next 1

Comment: ``next 1`` - you should explain row ordering.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

See this example

```
-- test data
create table test (id int,val int);
insert into test values(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,1),(5,4),(6,5);
-- query
select gr,string_agg(val,'') res
from(
  select * 
    ,sum(case when val=1 then 1 else 0 end)over(order by id)gr
  from test
  )x
group by gr
```

subQuery result

| id | val | gr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 4 | 2 |
| 6 | 5 | 2 |

gr - count of value `1` ordering by `id`

Query result - after groupping

| gr | res |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 145 |